# Vidalia running without GUI

Tags: vidalia, fedora

I'm using `Vidalia` on my Fedora. When I wanted to start `Vidalia` by clicking the icon, it starts but there is no GUI in screen. In System Monitor it shows Vidalia process and also I can connect to Tor.

Also I have installed `Vidalia` again but same problem appeared .

It works with GUI in past days but today this problem appeared. What is wrong with `Vidalia'?

Answer (score 2):

Vidalia may be running in minimized format. Find the minimized Vidalia icon and maximize it, or take it out of the minimized format by any means available to you. There should not be anything wrong with Vidalia at this point in time as far as I know. Please feel free to correct me or append this answer if more accurate information is available.